# My website height is too large when viewed on an ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad, height, containers

My website can be found at [FlatWaterTuesday](http://www.flatwatertuesday.com)

The site looks fine on a laptop but when I look at it on an ipad the links within the page jerk down to much lower than all the content. It looks to me as though I haven't set the correct height of either the body or the container for an ipad (I am using media queries for this). The source code can be found online. Please help!

Comment: General advice: you will get negative comments and votes if you simply ask people to debug your website. Consider making a JSFiddle with the offending code to save us from sifting through a mass of html and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick peek at your code, and while I didn't dig too deep, here are a few places to start:

- Change the `<meta viewport>` value to only `width=device-width`. Leave the others out and only add ones you're sure will help the experience you're trying to set. For most people that's enough, but `initial-scale` is sometimes helpful in certain situations.
- Also, I'd avoid declaring my media queries with `min/max-device-width`, and instead use `min/max-width`. If I go below 1224px on my desktop, which is pretty likely, there's no CSS at all.
- Finally, in your ipad.css, you have `width: 10000px` on both `body` and `.container`, and other widths throughout that go above 1024px. A width of 100%, or a pixel value that better suits the iPad resolution, would be more appropriate.